# how to get value of item in array of list and make them independent list

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I have list like example below, I want to get value of nameCategory and make them to List

```
List<Categories> iconCategory= [
  Categories(
    iconPath: 'assets/images/icons/IncomeIcon/001-salary.svg',
    nameCategory: 'Salary',
  ),
  Categories(
    iconPath: 'assets/images/icons/IncomeIcon/002-interest.svg',
    nameCategory: 'Interest',
  ),
  Categories(
    iconPath: 'assets/images/icons/IncomeIcon/003-award.svg',
    nameCategory: 'Award',
  )];
```

to list like example below but the data is from array list above
how I can do that

```
List<String> myCategory = ['Salary','Interest','Award'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the [map](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) method to achieve this:

```
List<String> myCategory = mycategories.map((e) => e.nameCategory).toList();
print(myCategory); // Prints [Salary, Interest, Award]
```

Answer (score 0):

this will  give you what you need

```
List<Categories> s1 = [];
List<String> ss = [];
result!.map((e) {
  ss.add(e.nameCategory);
});
```

Comment: thanks for answer but I need to convert all value with all index to list